# Create an infinite stream from a list

Tags: list, stream, scheme, racket, infinite

I'm trying to create an infinite stream from a list using racket. I was told not to use `set!`. The instruction is to create a local environment to store a copy of the list so that I can use the copy when the list being iterated is empty.

For example, if I have a list `(a, b)` (I know this is not how racket represent lists, but just to make it easier to read), I want to get an infinite stream of `(a, b, a, b, a, b, ...)`

Here is the current code I have.

```
(define (copy l) (stream l))

(define (infinite-stream l)
  (if (stream-empty? l)
      (infinite-stream (copy l))
      (stream-cons (stream-first l) (infinite-stream (stream-rest l)))))
```

and obviously, it is not working. after checking `(if (stream-empty? l)`, how should I pass in the original list?

** I cannot use for loop!

Thanks! let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: `copy` is the same as `stream`; you're not storing a copy anywhere. Are you really supposed to use Racket streams rather than implement your own?

Comment: I just wanted to make a copy of the original list. I was told to use stream because I'll have to loop it over infinitely.

Comment: Can you post the actual description of the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, we want to construct `infinite-stream` which transforms a list of elements into a stream of elements which repeats the input list infinitely.

```
;; infinite-stream :: list -> stream
(define (infinite-stream xs)
  ...)
```

Let's also write some examples to remind us how things should work:

```
(stream->list (stream-take (infinite-stream (list 1 2 3)) 10))
;; expect (list 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

The argument is a list `xs`, so as usual, there are two possibilities: either it's `empty` or `cons`. Therefore, we can perform a case-analysis on it.

```
;; infinite-stream :: list -> stream
(define (infinite-stream xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) ...]
    [else ;; here we have (first xs) and (rest xs) available
          ...]))
```

What should we do in the base case, when `xs` is `empty`? Let's take a look at our example. At some point, `(infinite-stream (list 1 2 3))` would call `(infinite-stream (list 2 3))` which calls `(infinite-stream (list 3))` which then calls `(infinite-stream (list))`. But now we are stuck! At this point, we still want to generate infinitely many elements more, but we don't have any information that we can use at all, because the argument is just `empty`. The data `1`, `2`, and `3` are not available to us, but we need them to continue the process.

So, instead, let's suppose that we magically have the very original data `orig-xs` available to us (and let's rename the function to `infinite-stream-helper`):

```
;; infinite-stream-helper :: list, list -> stream
(define (infinite-stream-helper xs orig-xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) ...]
    [else ;; here we have (first xs) and (rest xs) available
          ...]))
```

The meaning of `infinite-stream-helper` is: construct an infinite stream of repeating elements from `orig-xs` but in the first "round", use elements from `xs` instead.

Here are some examples:

```
(stream->list (stream-take (infinite-stream-helper (list) (list 1 2 3)) 10))
;; expect (list 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)

(stream->list (stream-take (infinite-stream-helper (list 3) (list 1 2 3)) 10))
;; expect (list 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3)

(stream->list (stream-take (infinite-stream-helper (list 2 3) (list 1 2 3)) 10))
;; expect (list 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2)

(stream->list (stream-take (infinite-stream-helper (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3)) 10))
;; expect (list 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

It is now possible to write the base case! I will leave you to fill it up. Hint: what should be the result of `(infinite-stream-helper (list) (list 1 2 3))`? How is that result related to the result of `(infinite-stream-helper (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))`?

Now, for the recursive case, what should we do? Let's take a look at the example. Suppose now we are dealing with `(infinite-stream-helper (list 2 3) (list 1 2 3))` which should result in a stream of `2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...`.

That's just putting `2` in front of a stream of `3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...`. Do we know how to construct a stream of `3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...`? Yes! That's just `(infinite-stream-helper (list 3) (list 1 2 3))`!

```
;; infinite-stream-helper :: list, list -> stream
(define (infinite-stream-helper xs orig-xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) ... FILL THIS IN ...]
    [else (stream-cons (first xs) (infinite-stream-helper (rest xs) orig-xs))]))
```

But we are not quite done. What we originally want is `infinite-stream`, not `infinite-stream-helper`, but it should now be easy to define `infinite-stream` from `infinite-stream-helper`.

```
;; infinite-stream :: list -> stream
(define (infinite-stream xs)
  ... FILL THIS IN ...)
```

Comment: Wow!! Very thorough... Gave me a clear idea on how to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is (in pseudocode; being *bold* about it)

```
cycle xs  =  xs, xs, xs, xs, xs, xs .......
```

where `xs` is the input list, and `,` is intended as a sequence-concatenation operator.

It's the same `xs` all over, infinite number of times, which is understandably a bit daunting and confusing.

But if we look closer we can see that this is the same as

```
cycle xs  =  xs, (xs, xs, xs, xs, xs .......)
          =  xs, cycle xs
```

thus the problem is reduced to implementing the concatenation operator where we now have just two streams to use it with -- one equivalent to the input list `xs`, and the other is just a call to `cycle`:

```
(define (cycle xs)
    (stream-concat (list-stream xs) (cycle xs)))
```

Define `stream-concat`.

Define `list-stream`.

Done. Or if you want to be extra efficient about it, fuse the two definitions inside the higher-level `cycle` together into a more efficient definition.

Comment: I see the idea. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (list->infstream lst)
    (define (list->stream l)
      (cond ((null? l) (list->infstream lst))
            (else (stream-cons (car l) (list->stream (cdr l))))))
    (list->stream lst))
```

Instead of returning `empty-stream` when at end of the list, return a new inifinite stream!

For testing, you need

```
(define (stream-take stream n)
  "Take first n elements of stream lazily"
  (if (zero? n)
      empty-stream
      (stream-cons (stream-first stream)
                   (stream-take (stream-rest stream) (- n 1)))))
```

To first make out of the infinite stream first a finite stream.

```
(stream->list (stream-take (list->infstream '(a b c)) 10))
;;=> '(a b c a b c a b c a)
```